# Aligning material of two or more cases environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases

The following code

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{align*}
 a=&
   \begin{cases}
   b,&\ \text{if}\ c\,;\\
   d,&\ \text{if}\ e\,;\\
   f,&\ \text{otherwise}\,.
   \end{cases}\\[3mm]
 g=&
   \begin{cases}
   h,&\ \text{if}\ i\,;\\
   j,&\ \text{if}\ k\,;\\
   l,&\ \text{otherwise}\,,
   \end{cases}
 \end{align*}
 \end{document}
```

---

yields

[image: output with braces but not completely aligned]

What I really want is to align the clauses of the two sets of cases as well, that is, I want something like this, **including the two left braces** (which, of course, are missing; otherwise I wouldn't be asking):

[image: desired output, except for the lacking braces]

By the way, the code for the "aligned but without braces" example above is the following:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{equation*}
 \begin{aligned}
   &\ \ bbbb,\ & &\text{if}\ c\,;\\
 a=&\ \ dd,\ & &\text{if}\ e\,;\\
   &\ \ fffff,\ & &\text{otherwise}\,.\\[3mm]
   &\ \ h,\ & &\text{if}\ i\,;\\
 g=&\ \ jjjjjjjjj,\ & &\text{if}\ k\,;\\
   &\ \ l,\ & &\text{otherwise}\,,
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}
 \end{document}
```

---

I tried to introduce `\left\{` (resp. `\right`) at the most natural places, namely, right before "bbbb" and "h" (resp. right after the two instances of "otherwise."), without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the longest entry, a solution may be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}


 \newlength{\myjjj}
 \begin{equation*}
  \settowidth{\myjjj}{$jjjjjjjjj,$} %longest entry
 \begin{aligned}
 &
 a=\begin{cases}
 \makebox[\myjjj][l]{$bbbb,$}\ &\text{if}\ c\,;\\
 dd,\ &\text{if}\ e\,;\\
 fffff,\ &\text{otherwise}\,.\\[3mm]
 \end{cases}\\
 &g=\begin{cases}
    h,\  &\text{if}\ i\,;\\
 jjjjjjjjj,\  &\text{if}\ k\,;\\
 l,\ & \text{otherwise}\,,
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Btw mathtools have a mathmakebox, then you do not need to wrap the contents in dollars